# Symfony 3 form and one-to-many

Tags: php, symfony, one-to-many

This seems to be an easy task, but I can't figure out the best solution. I have bidirectional one-to-many relation between trainer and teams (one trainer can have many teams). When I add / edit a trainer I want to assign him team/teams. I got no error, but nothing happens. My guess is that this has something to do with the relation, owning side or something similar. There's another relation: players - team and everything works fine, but in this case I have a player form and I assign team to a player.

So if I submit a form from "many" perspective, it works, but when I try to do it from "one" persepctive, I still get null in db and relation is not being established.

Trainer.php:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Team", mappedBy="trainer")
*/
private $teams;
...
$this->teams = new ArrayCollection();
```

Team.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Trainer", inversedBy="teams")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="trainer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $trainer;
```

TrainerType.php:

```
        ->add('teams', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Team',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label' => 'Teams',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->where('t.isMyTeam = 1')    
                    ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
            },              
        ));
```

Is there a way to make it work with one to many relation? Or should I switch to many-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is connected with owning side and inverse side. If you add relation as the owning side it will work but not the other way. Read this in [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side) and this about [owning side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association).

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the concept of uni- / bidirectional. I vhange the relation to One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table and it works now.